# Drupal CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, css, drupal

I'm working on a project where I made a copy of a live site on to my `localhost` to work on. I've made updates to a sub theme css/js, added the new CSS file to the sub theme `.info` file, and modified the `preprocess_page` and added the JS with the `drupal_add_js` method.

All this seems to work very well on my `localhost`, but pushing live, the site still picks up the old CSS/JS files.

I cleared all caches I could find:

- Site Configuration/Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation/Smart cache flush
- Site Configuration/Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation/Cache Rebuild
- Site Configuration/Performance/Clear cached data

but I'm still getting the same result. The old CSS/JS files persist. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Cleared browser cache ?

Comment: yup, using different browsers, cleared all browser caches and have cache disabled in safari while i'm testing.

Comment: Does your live site have additional caching e.g. Varnish? Also do you have the Color module installed?

Comment: Is the problem here that you are struggling to add your own files, or struggling to remove old ones?

Comment: clear page cache of your drupal site if its enabled in live site. Can you tell us the css file path and js file path?

Comment: I think at this point i'm struggling to remove old files that i've combined. On my localhost which is an exact copy, i've got only the files i want. on live the files i don't want i can't seem to get rid off.

Comment: I've cleared all caches as best i could as i've found in the backend as per my above statement.

Where is it that one defines what css/js files are defined. Coz what i've done seems to be right from what i can discern but its not changing anything

Comment: Question might be a better fit over here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Drupal sometimes jamming, despite cleaning the caches...

I was then helped by **deleting files from these folders**:

```
./sites/default/files/css
./sites/default/files/js
```

Note: *If you want this, instead of deleting it, you can move it to another folder.*